Scroll bar type controls to pan an SVG
I have an SVG where I want to pan the view box over the image. For example if I have an SVG with elements anywhere over an area 0->1000 by 0->1000 and I set the (square) viewbox to 0 0 500 500 I get the top left quarter; I set the view box to 250 250 500 500 I get the middle all as expected.
I have:
<svg viewbox="@svgViewBox"...... >.....
private string SvgViewBox => $"{PanHorizontal} {PanVertical} {ViewBoxWidth} {ViewBoxHeight}";
I can set values of PanHorizontal and PanVertical etc to show various parts of the SVG
I would really like something like scroll bars to bind to PanHorizontal and PanVertical . I've tried FluentSlider with horizontal and vertical alignment but can't figure out how to position them well around the SVG.
Is this a css problem? If so how do I place the controls to the right and below the svg?
Any thoughts?
I've made a few attempts to position the flutentslider's but I'm in the dark.

I wouldn't use scrollbars.  I'd use drag with a hand icon, so you can move it around like a map.

@Bennyboy1973 I am in two minds about that. On the one hand it is easy (for me, in this case) to implement, on there other there are may elements within the SVG that the user drags around... so the user would either need to find space in the "background" or toggle between dragging the whole image vs just an element. I don't know how to decide is scroll bars are better or worse.

I don't know what you're trying to do, so I can't really say that much.  All those options are viable.  I'm not sure how SVG interacts with javascript/html metrics-- I suspect you'd have to do your "dragging" with JavaScript, then calculate out how much objects (or the entire view) moved based on a scale variable.  But you don't want to have live updates to position calculated in C# based on drag events on server interactive, because it will fail when you add real-world web latency.  Might have to make that part WASM?

btw I gave a demo using slider.  This is because slider can have discrete steps, which greatly reduces latency from a pure drag in JavaScript.

Hi @Bennyboy1973 , the dragging part isn't really that hard. The mouse events on the svg in blazor work well. Only one JSinterop call needed at the start of a drag operation to get the size on screen of the svg element, and a function based on the size on screen, view box and mouse client coordinates gives me coordinates in the svg space. In my case the elements in the SVG are in groups so it is quick/ easy to traverse the group hierarchy   to get to the element that contains the coordinates of the pointer.
Panning the whole svg is fast (flicker free) by altering the view box of the svg

Just remember-- make sure you aren't doing interop between interactiver server and JavaScript for events that can fire very often, like drag events.  When you deploy them online, there will be problems that you don't have on your dev machine.  If you need fast feedback, you'll want it on the client side only.

@Bennyboy1973 WASM all the way

SVG is xml markup, much like HTML, which means you can parameterize whatever you want, in this case the offset of your view box.  You could literally make an entire site with all SVG, I think, including animations, etc.  I recommend making a separate .razor component for each shape.
Home.razor
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<div style="width:50vmin; height:50vmin; border: 1px solid black;
            cursor:grab">
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
        <Shape1 Xoffset=OffsetX Yoffset=OffsetY />
    </div>
    <div style="transform:rotate(90deg); padding-right:20px;transform-origin:top right;">
        <input @bind=OffsetY style="width:100%" type="range" min="-1000" max="1000" step="1">
    </div>
    <div style="height:20px; display:relative; margin-top:-40px;padding-right:20px">
        <input @bind=OffsetX style="width:100%" type="range" min="-1000" max="1000" step="1">
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    float OffsetX = 0.0f;
    float OffsetY = 0.0f;
}

Shape1.razor
<svg style="" viewBox="@Xoffset @Yoffset 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
<ellipse fill="#1E3B50" cx="548.8" cy="468.2" rx="363.4" ry="348" />
<g>
<g>
<path fill="#4995D1" d="M382.9,527.1c23.5,12.7,40.4,34,60.5,51.2c10.6,9.1,22.1,16.7,35.1,21.8c13.9,5.5,28.7,8.3,43.5,9.7
            c28.3,2.7,57,0.7,84.8-5c27.6-5.7,54.5-15.4,79.4-28.6c12.4-6.6,24.4-14,35.7-22.3c11.3-8.2,22.9-17.1,31.2-28.4
            c2.1-2.8,3.9-5.8,5.4-9c1.3-2.9-3-5.4-4.3-2.5c-5.9,12.7-17,22-27.9,30.4c-10.9,8.5-22.4,16.2-34.5,23.1c-24.1,13.7-50,24-77,30.5
            c-26.9,6.5-54.7,9.1-82.4,7.7c-14.8-0.8-29.6-2.7-43.7-7.1c-13.3-4.1-25.5-10.7-36.4-19.3c-20.5-16.1-36.8-37.1-58.7-51.5
            c-2.7-1.8-5.4-3.4-8.2-4.9C382.6,521.3,380,525.6,382.9,527.1L382.9,527.1z" />
    </g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<path fill="#4995D1" d="M657.6,305c-8,2-13.4,8.4-16.5,15.8c-3.4,8.1-4.7,16.9-5.6,25.6c-0.5,5.4-0.5,11.2,1.5,16.4
            c1.5,4,4,7.5,7.4,10.2c6.8,5.5,15.7,7.8,24.3,8.3c8.3,0.5,16.8-0.9,24.5-3.9c7.6-3,14.7-7.6,19.5-14.3c4.7-6.7,6.1-15.3,3.5-23.1
            c-2.9-8.7-9.9-15.3-17.2-20.5c-3.8-2.7-7.7-5.1-11.7-7.5c-4.7-2.8-9.5-5.6-14.3-8.1c-9.7-5-20-9-31-9.9c-2.6-0.2-5.2-0.2-7.8,0
            c-1.3,0.1-2.5,1.1-2.5,2.5c0,1.3,1.1,2.6,2.5,2.5c20.1-1.5,38.7,9.8,55.2,20c6.9,4.3,14.2,9.2,18.9,16.1
            c4.2,6.2,5.6,13.6,2.9,20.5c-2.4,6.2-8,11.1-13.9,14.4c-6.5,3.6-14,5.8-21.4,6.3c-7.6,0.5-15.7-0.4-22.6-3.7
            c-3.3-1.6-6.3-3.7-8.6-6.6c-2.6-3.3-3.9-7.4-4.1-11.6c-0.3-4.7,0.3-9.6,0.9-14.3c0.5-3.9,1.3-7.7,2.3-11.5
            c1.9-6.5,4.9-13.5,10.8-17c1.5-0.9,2.8-1.4,4.5-1.8C662.1,309.1,660.7,304.3,657.6,305L657.6,305z" />
    </g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<path fill="#4995D1" d="M440.5,250.9c-16,11.7-28,28.2-34.6,46.9c-3.2,9.2-5,18.9-5.3,28.7c-0.1,5.1-0.1,10.5,1.8,15.3
            c1.9,4.8,5.6,8.3,10.3,10.3c4.5,1.9,9.4,2.6,14.3,3.1c5,0.5,9.9,0.6,14.9,0.3c9.9-0.6,19.7-2.6,29-6c9.4-3.4,18.3-8.2,26.2-14.2
            c4-3,7.9-6.3,11.3-10c3.6-3.9,6.7-9.3,4.6-14.7c-1.9-5-6.6-8.1-10.8-11c-4.5-3.2-9.1-6.1-13.9-8.8c-9.7-5.4-20-9.8-30.6-13.1
            c-2.6-0.8-5.2-1.5-7.8-2.2c-3.1-0.8-4.5,4-1.3,4.8c10.1,2.5,19.9,6.1,29.2,10.6c4.7,2.3,9.2,4.8,13.6,7.5
            c4.3,2.6,8.7,5.4,12.6,8.7c3.2,2.7,6,6.1,3.9,10.4c-2.1,4.2-6.1,7.5-9.6,10.5c-7,6-15,10.9-23.4,14.6c-8.3,3.7-17.3,6.2-26.3,7.3
            c-9.1,1.2-18.6,1.2-27.6-0.6c-4.1-0.8-8.3-2.1-11.3-5.1c-3.3-3.3-4-8.2-4.1-12.6c-0.3-9.1,0.9-18.2,3.4-26.9
            c5-17.5,15-33.6,28.9-45.4c1.7-1.4,3.4-2.8,5.1-4c1.1-0.8,1.6-2.2,0.9-3.4C443.3,250.7,441.6,250.1,440.5,250.9L440.5,250.9z" />
    </g>
</g>
</svg>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public float Xoffset { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public float Yoffset { get; set; }
}


Hi, this has helped me figure out how to place the Fluent-UI sliders where I wanted them. Thank you

A parent element of the SVG can handle the scroll bars:


div.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    width="1000" height="1000">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="orange"  />
  </svg>
</div>




Thanks for the answer, I've come from coding more than UI design, so I think I am not sure about a few things.
With your answer:
How does the app code "know" what part of the SVG is visible?
How can the app code control what part of the SVG is being shown?
How do the numeric values you have included in your answer map to the values I mention in my question?

I have another thought about your answer: I can see that scroll bars will be rendered to pan around the content of the view box, but cant see how it helps move the view box over the SVG.
